# What is $\lim\limits_{t \rightarrow \infty}e^{-{it}}$

Tags: limits, analysis, distribution-theory

Let $f(t)=e^{-it}$, $t \geq 0$.
We know that f doesn't converge when t goes to infinity. But does it converge as a distribution?

Comment: What is *convergence as a distribution*?

Comment: It means we take a compactly supported function $ f $ and we see in this case if $ \int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-it} f(t) dt $ exists.

Comment: You want to consider for fixed $t$ the distribution $f(t) \varphi = e^{-it} \int \varphi(x) dx$? Or do you perhaps mean to consider the distribution $$ f(t)\varphi = \int e^{-itx} \varphi(x) = \hat{\varphi}(t).$$ The second one is much better behaved.

Comment: The existence of the integral $\int e^{-it} f(t) dt$ for $f$ a test function (bad notation as we already used $f$) is trivial. You integrate two continuous functions on a compact interval.

Comment: But now I'm confused  about the definition of convergence as a distribution ! I think your second definition: $f(t)\phi = \hat{\phi}(t)$ is the right one ! What can we say about the limit of $\hat{\phi}(t)$ ?

Comment: Note that all you need for a function $f$ to define a distribution is that $f$ is integrable on all compacta. As we always integrate it against compactly supported functions, this is enough.

Comment: Well, by the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma, we have that $\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} \hat{\varphi}(t)=0$ (holds actually for all $L^1$ functions).

Comment: Ok I see, I didn't knew about this theorem. Thanks a lot @SeverinSchraven for your help and have a nice day!

Comment: You're welcome :) Happy Easter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me collect the info that you can also find scattered in the comments. There are several versions of what we could be talking about here:

1.) If we really mean "does $f(t)=e^{-it}$ for fixed $t$ define a distribution"? The answer for this is yes. Indeed, any function $g$ which is integrable on all compacta defines a distribution via
$$ T_g(\varphi) := \int_\mathbb{R} g(x) \varphi(x) $$
where the integral exists for all test functions $\varphi$ (as they have compact support). In particular the function $f_t(x) = e^{-it}$ (constant function) defines a distribution.

2.) We could now also ask whether the family of distributions defined by $T_{f(t)}$ converges in the space of distributions. That is clearly not the case as we have
$$ T_{f(t)}(\varphi) = e^{-it} \int_\mathbb{R} \varphi(x) dx, $$
hence we cannot take the limit $t\rightarrow \infty$.

3.) Finally we can consider the same question, but with $F_t(x)=e^{-itx}$. In this case we have
$$ T_{F_t}(\varphi) = \hat{\varphi}(t). $$
By the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma we have for any $g\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$
$$ \lim_{\vert \xi \vert \rightarrow \pm \infty} \hat{g}(\xi) = 0. $$
In particular, we have this convergence for test functions.

Comment: $\langle \lim_{x\to\pm\infty} u(x), \varphi(x) \rangle$ can (somewhat loosely) be defined as $\lim_{R\to\pm\infty} \langle u(x), \varphi(x-R) \rangle.$

Comment: @md2perpe Could you elaborate on that? It sounds like an answer I'd like to read :D

Answer (score 2):

When one talks about convergence in the space of distributions one usually has a parameter that is not the ordinary space variable. Examples:

1. $e^{ikx} \to 0$ as $k\to\pm\infty$ since $\langle e^{ikx}, \varphi(x) \rangle \to 0$ for every test function $\varphi$ as $k\to\pm\infty.$
2. $\frac{1}{\epsilon}e^{-x^2/\epsilon^2} \to \sqrt{\pi}\,\delta(x)$ as $\epsilon\to 0.$

So what would we mean with something like $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty} f(x)$ in the space of distributions? I would define it as
$$\lim_{R\to\pm\infty} \langle f(x), \varphi(x-R) \rangle.$$
For this particular example, $f(x)=e^{-ix}$ this limit does *not* exist. The value will just "spin around" on some circle centered at origin in the complex plane.

But for the similar function $g(x)=e^{-ix^2}$ (or with a plus sign) the limit exists and equals $0$. Therefore I would say that $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty} g(x) = 0$ in a distributional sense.

An even more interesting example is $h(x) = e^{ie^{x^2}}.$ This function is bounded and continuous and therefore is a [tempered distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)#Tempered_distributions_and_Fourier_transform), meaning that it has a Fourier transform. Therefore its derivative $h'(x) = 2x\,ie^{x^2}\,e^{ie^{x^2}}$ is also a tempered distribution, despite being far from bounded. But in the distributional sense defined above, the factor $e^{ie^{x^2}}$ tends to $0$ so fast as $x\to\pm\infty$ (by its oscillations) that also $e^{x^2}e^{ie^{x^2}}$ tends to $0$ in the distributional sense.

(I must admit that my last example made me a bit confused, so I hope that what I wrote is correct. My confusion lies in me thinking that if a tempered distribution like $h'$ is multiplied with a bounded function like $e^{-ie^{x^2}}$ then the result should also be a tempered distribution, which is not the case here. **EDIT**: I realized that a tempered distribution can not be multiplied with bounded functions in general. Also the derivatives of all orders need to be bounded. Here the factor $e^{-ie^{x^2}}$ fails.)